# Gradle sync failed ned to fix

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've just migrate my solution from another computer but i was getting a Gradle sync error, anyone can resolve this problem? thanks in advance :)

this is my error I've got:

[image]

this is my project gradle:
[image]

and this is my app gradle:[image]

Comment: how are your `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` files like?

Comment: sorry sir?newbie here. what do  you mean with that? :)

Comment: you should have those two files under your android project, try to post them so that I can help review your gradle configurations to solve your sync issue if possible.

Comment: just got edited sir.. :)

Comment: `no route to host`, is your current host behind proxy?

Comment: just got fixed, my internet was not stable so that the gradle sync unavalable due to lost of network connection. also ive just disabled my wifi and get a wired intenet to have a stable network access..

Comment: by the way thanks for helping me.